# NSView setNeedsDisplay not available

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa

I've written a Cocoa app in Objective-C that does some drawing in a CustomView on a nib file. The Custom View is updated by calling "[theView setNeedsDisplay:YES]" from my view controller class, and everything works as it should. But when I converted this app to Swift 2.1, I'm unable to update the view using "theView.setNeedsDisplay()" (with or without "true") Auto-complete doesn't offer this call, and when I try to use it in spite of this, I get an error that says the class doesn't have a member called "setNeedsDisplay". Everything else in the app works exactly as the Objective-C version does. Has anyone else had this problem? I'm running XCode 7.1.1 on El Capitan.

Comment: Just double-checking, your `CustomView` is subclassed from `UIView`?

Comment: Try `theView.needsDisplay = true`

Comment: theView.displayIfNeeded()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least in Yosemite `needsDisplay` is declared as a property.

Unlike Objective-C where the implicit setter syntax `setNeedsDisplay` can be used, `set<Ivar>` is not available in Swift due to its solely dot syntax.

You have to write

```
myView.needsDisplay = true
```